# Product Chooser in Custom Module

Tags: product-chooser

I am wondering if this is possible.

I would like to create same functionality as this image in my custom module.

[image]

I could use a widget- product chooser, however that is letting me choose only one product. I need to select more than one product.

I will have just a button where I can click and then it will render the product chooser grid and then when selected multiple items, it sends `id or sku` in the input field.

Then later on I will save this info in to database.

Please suggest.

Comment: Why not do like `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid` with `_prepareMassaction`?

Comment: Yes, but have to save all other data in same time. Good to reduce the steps.

Comment: Have you find the script for this? Please post here how to use in custom module?

Answer (score 3):

This feature relies heavily on the Javascript vor the Magento Promotional rules.

It's location in file `js/mage/adminhtml/rules.js`. The method you want to look at is `showChooserElement`, which is called by `initParam`, this part to be exact.

```
var trig = elem.down('.rule-chooser-trigger');
if (trig) {
   Event.observe(trig, 'click', this.toggleChooser.bind(this, container));
}
```

So calling `VarienRulesForm.showChooserElement(element);` with the right kind of element (having all the required attributes) should in theory give you the chooser. Still, you'll need to do a lot of tweaking I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Updating for an old thread,

but I had the same issue and after searching for ALOT on SO threads I decided to make one. Just finished adding it to a git, it basically shows a button on an admin form that will launch a widget that can choose multiple products at once. I'll leave the github link.

https://github.com/ManZzup/Magento-Multi-Product-Chooser

Instead of showing the product chooser in the form, this will show a popup box (or a modal) that contains the product selection. All other features work as in the selector above.